# PHP + Quickbook Online Edition (API Integration)?

Tags: php, api, integration, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

Is it possible to integrate my PHP web-based ecommerce application with Quickbook Online Edition?

When I make a sale on my web site, I would like to be able to make the corresponding journal entry in my accounting books.

Note, I'm referring to Quickbook **Online Edition**, **not** the desktop software.

Comment: I added some examples and a link to some code for integration QuickBooks Online Edition with PHP applications to one of my posts. Might be worth taking a look at for you.

Answer (score 15):

I now have built a set of PHP classes that facilitates communication with QuickBooks Online Edition. It makes communicating with QuickBooks Online Edition as easy as:

```
// Create the connection to QuickBooks
$API = new QuickBooks_API(...);

// Build the Customer object
$Customer = new QuickBooks_Object_Customer();
$Customer->setName($name);
$Customer->setShipAddress('134 Stonemill Road', '', '', '', '', 'Storrs', 'CT', '', '06268');

// Send the request to QuickBooks
$API->addCustomer($Customer, '_add_customer_callback', 15);

// The framework also supports processing raw qbXML requests
$API->qbxml('
    <CustomerQueryRq>
        <FullName>Keith Palmer Jr.</FullName>
    </CustomerQueryRq>', '_raw_qbxml_callback');
```

You can download the framework from my thread here:
[QuickBooks Online Edition PHP Package](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=9164)

I've started writing some documentation/tips on how to integrate web applications with QuickBooks Online Edition here: 
[QuickBooks Integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can send qbXML requests to QuickBooks Online Edition, just as you can send qbXML requests to regular desktop editions of QuickBooks.

Download the QuickBooks SDK for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Quickbooks OE has an XML-based SDK, available at:

http://developer.intuit.com/technical_resources/default.aspx?id=1492